# How to determine in a nonlinear circuit with multiple diodes which diode is ON vs which one is OFF? Does it depend on the orientation of circuit?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, diodes, circuits

This problem is from the Sedra Smith *Microelectronic Circuits* textbook 7th edition. There are solutions available online but I am having trouble how they determined that in part b, D1 is forward biased and D2 is reverse biased. How did they determine that in part a D1 is reverse biased and D2 is forward biased? Some videos mentioned that one should choose the diode attached to the higher input voltage and others mentioned the opposite.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This kind of problem is solved by a guess-and-check method.

Say in part (a) you guessed that both diodes are forward biased. Then you'd find that node "V" must be at +1 V  (assuming a very simple model with 0 forward voltage) because of D1 being forward biased. But "V" must be at +2 V because of D2 being forward biased. Those both can't be true at the same time so we have a contradiction and so this guess must be wrong. Try some other guess until you get one that gives no contradiction.

> Some videos mentioned that one should choose the diode attached to the higher input Voltage and others mentioned the opposite.

It's going to matter, for example, is it the anode or the cathode of the diode that's connected to a lower or a higher voltage. So the two videos might be totally correct to give different rules, if they were looking at different problems.

Answer (score 1):

In 4.3(a) start by asking if the \$-3\:\text{V}\$ is more negative than either or both of the sources at the diode anodes. The answer is ***yes*** in this case. So you know that at least one of the two diodes is **on**. Next, if either \$D_1\$ or \$D_2\$ is **on** then \$V\$ is either \$+2\:\text{V}\$ or else \$+1\:\text{V}\$. If \$V=+1\:\text{V}\$ then this would violate the ***ideal*** case for \$D_2\$, which would now be forward-biased by \$1\:\text{V}\$. So \$V=+2\:\text{V}\$, diode \$D_2\$ is **on** and at this point you know, by definition, that \$D_1\$ must be **off**. Done.

In 4.3(b) start by asking if the \$+3\:\text{V}\$ is more positive than either or both of the sources at the diode cathods. The answer is ***yes*** in this case, too. So you know that at least one of the two diodes is **on**. Next, if either \$D_1\$ or \$D_2\$ is **on** then \$V\$ is either \$+2\:\text{V}\$ or else \$+1\:\text{V}\$. (Same question as before.) If \$V=+2\:\text{V}\$ then this would violate the ***ideal*** case for \$D_1\$, which would now be forward-biased by \$1\:\text{V}\$. So \$V=+1\:\text{V}\$, diode \$D_1\$ is **on** and at this point you know, by definition, that \$D_2\$ must be **off**. Done, again.

Comment: I have a question i hope it doesnt sound dumb. Why cant both D1 and D2 be forward biased in part b?

Comment: @user364328 Assuming these are truly *ideal diodes*, then there is no voltage drop across them when they are **ON**. So if both were **ON** then in part (b) ***V*** would have to be both +1 V and +2 V simultaneously. That cannot actually be true.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is as follows. In part (a), both diode cathodes have the same potential, \$V\$. The diode which is *most* forward biased will be the one whose *anode* has the higher potential. That's D2.

In part (b) both *anodes* have the same potential, \$V\$. The one that is most forward biased will be the one that has the lowest cathode potential. That's D1.

In this sense, the videos are correct. These are, however, just guesses for the moment. Whether they are justified is yet to be seen.

Now you consider what effect a forward biased diode has on the common node V. In part (a), the most forward biased diode (D2) can never have more than 0.7V across it. In other words, its cathode cannot be lower than 0.7V less than its anode, so potential at node V should be:

$$ V = (+2V) - 0.7V = +1.3V $$

Instantly it's clear that the other diode, D1, is in fact, *reverse* biased, since its cathode \$V=+1.3V\$ is *higher* in potential than its anode at +1.0V. With negligible current through it, it can't influence V, and our initial "guess" was justified.

For part (b) we take the same approach. In this case, as we established before, D1 is the most forward biased, passing most current, and it cannot have more than 0.7V across it. In other words, D1's anode would be 0.7V higher than its cathode:

$$ V = (+1.0V) + 0.7V = +1.7V $$

Consequently, D2's anode potential is lower than its cathode, and D2 is therefore reverse biased, having no influence. Again, our initial instincts were justified.

Answer (score 0):

## Is it worth looking for the meaning of circuits?

There are two ways to analyze circuits, each with advantages and disadvantages:

- One is to analyze circuits formally without caring about what it is, what it is for, what the idea behind it is, etc. It is versatile and works if our goal is to do our homework or get an exam but not if we want to deeply understand circuits. Analyzing many seemingly disparate circuits in this way does little to help understanding them.
- The other is to try to see the meaning of circuits, the ideas on which they are built, and accumulate them for future use. In this way, we can reduce the variety of circuits to a small number of typical circuit solutions. But it is difficult and slow and, therefore, often neglected. Regardless, I have a preference for this approach and will use it here.

## Basic idea

These diode circuits switch to their output the highest (Schematic "a") or the lowest (Schematic "b") of several input voltages. Their most famous applications are *backup power supplies*, *diode logic gates*, etc.

## How to reveal it

### Common rules

Understanding such *diode-switch circuits* can be done by following some simple rules:

- Trace the diode current paths.
- For this purpose, connect the input voltage sources to the circuit.
- Initially, replace the diodes with conceptual switches.
- Break down the circuit into variants with one, the other, and finally both diodes.
- Build the circuit step by step moving from the simple to the complex.

## Voltage sources in parallel...

If we directly connect two (or more) voltage sources with different voltages in parallel, a high (theoretically infinite) equilizing current will flow from the source with the higher voltage to the other one. This is undesired and the simulator does not allow it. To limit the current (e.g., to 1 A), I have set small (0.5 Ω) ammeter resistances.

**V1 = 1 V, V2 = 2 V:** So the current flows from V2 to V1...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flbjvt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**V1 = 2 V, V2 = 1 V:** ... or from V1 to V2, and the output voltage (1.5 V) is between the two input voltages as a result of the "tug of war" between them.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEQXNQ.png)</sup>

## ... through switches...

Apparently the input voltages would have to be switched with some kind of switches.

**Maximum voltage selector:** To select the higher voltage, the switch SW2 should be turned on...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3fo4M.png)</sup>

**Minimum voltage selector:** ... and accordingly, to select the lower voltage, the switch SW1 should be turned on.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4aXIc.png)</sup>

## ... implemented with diodes

As we know, the conceptual switches above can be implemented by (ideal) diodes with 0 V forward voltage when *closed*. They are controlled by the input voltages.

**Maximum voltage selector:** If they face their anodes to the positive terminals of the input sources, the diode controlled by the voltage source with the higher voltage is *on*, and the output voltage is 2 V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFuK3Z.png)</sup>

**Minimum voltage selector:** If they face their cathodes to the positive terminals of the input sources, the diode controlled by the voltage source with the lower voltage should be *on*, and the output voltage should be 1 V. But to our surprise it is not so much but only a few mV. Why?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffZKN2.png)</sup>

The problem is that the voltmeter's resistance is not infinite ("ideal" voltmeter) but "only" 1 GΩ. It acts as a "pull down" resistor that easily "pulls" the diode anodes to ground. So, if we remove the voltmeter and hover the mouse over the output, the simulator will show exactly 1 V.

[image: 1.3.2.2_600]

Another trick is to compare the anode voltage with 1 V reference voltage. The voltmeter now acts as a null indicator NI showing the result of comparison. The reference voltage acts as an output voltage Vout.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHiT7P.png)</sup>

## "Pulling" resistors added

The best solution is to forward bias the diodes by another voltage source through a "pulling" resistor.

**Maximum voltage selector:** In the first case, the resistor "pulls" the cathodes to some negative voltage (-3 V). Note that the input and output voltage sources are connected in series in the same direction so their voltages are added.

**V1 = 1 V:** D1 is forward-biased.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foB1ym.png)</sup>

**V2 = 2 V:** D2 is forward-biased.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPyUsQ.png)</sup>

**V1 = 1 V, V2 = 2 V:** Only D2 is forward-biased and V2 appears at the output. Why?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHduKg.png)</sup>

The simplest explanation is to consider the loop V1-D1-D2-V2. Then we see that the resulting voltage V2-V1 applied across the D1-D2 network makes D1 backward biased and D2 forward biased. So D1 is *off* and D2 *on*, and V2 appears at the output.

**Minimum voltage selector:** In the second case, the resistor "pulls" the anodes to some positive voltage (3 V). Now the input and output voltage sources are connected in series but in the opposite direction so their voltages are subtracted.

**V1 = 1 V:** D1 is forward-biased.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxAUlg.png)</sup>

**V2 = 2 V:** D2 is forward-biased.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffyTNn.png)</sup>

**V1 = 1 V, V2 = 2 V:** Only D1 is forward-biased and V1 appears at the output. But why?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFqAXP.png)</sup>

As above, if we consider the loop V1-D1-D2-V2, we will see that now the resulting voltage V2-V1 applied across the D1-D2 network makes D1 forward biased and D2 backward biased. So D1 is *on* and D2 *off*, and V1 appears at the output.